# Leading zeros in Hexadecimal int variable C

Tags: c, hex, type-conversion, zero

I converting binary to HEXA but i need output with leading zeros. I use this number in this function -> creat(outfile, hexa_num); From 011101110111 I will get 777 but i need 0777. Here is my converting function. Any suggestions ?

```
char bin_final[]="011101110111";

char *a = bin_final;
    int hexa_num = 0;
    do {
        int b = *a=='1'?1:0;
        hexa_num = (hexa_num<<1)|b;
        a++;
    } while (*a);
```

Comment: Have you tried *printing* it with leading zeroes? Like e.g. `printf("%04x\n", hexa_num);`?

Comment: So you have a binary representation of a number `011101110111` but you actually want the number `111111111₂` (the first digit and every fourth digit after it removed). Keep a counter in your loop and ignore it when the remainder when divided by 4 is right, I guess.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't really convert to *hexadecimal*. You convert a string with binary digits, to a value in binary format. On binary computers (which are just about *all* computers these days) *all* values are stored in binary. Hexadecimal, decimal or octal are just how you *present* the binary value.

Comment: Adding extra zeros while storing a value is not possible in `C`, but you can add them while printing the value. See format specifiers in C

Comment: The code snippet converts a string to binary, but the question asks how to convert binary to a string.  Somebody is very confused, not so sure it is me.

Comment: Lastly, what if the string you want to convert is *empty*? Or contain non-binary digits? The first problem is solved with a `while` loop instead of a `do-while`. The second by checking the characters, and handling the error appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just use [`strtoul()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) and regular [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), no need to re-invent anything.

```
const unsigned long number = strtoul("011101110111", NULL, 2);
char buf[16];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%04lx", number);
puts(buf);
```

This prints

```
0777
```

Of course if you want to always just print it you can collapse the final three lines into just:

```
printf("%04lx\n", number);
```

Comment: So now I have this number in char[] and how i get it to int because creat takes int flags.

Comment: The first line calls `strtoul()`  to convert a string in binary into an `unsigned long` integer. If that was all you needed, your question is very confusing.

Comment: now I have 0777 in buf. But i need put buf to int creat(const char *path, mode_t mode) and it do not take char and if I convert buf to int I will get 777 not 0777. Hope its more clear now.

Comment: @KuboBrehuv -- it is not clear at all; if `creat()` takes an `int` argument, pass it an `int` value. No need to make a hex string representation. Leading zeros are part of the way the number is _presented_ when you print it; internally the numbers associated with `777` and `0777` are the same.

Comment: after 'creat("filename", 0777)' file rights will be -rwxrwxrwx but if  creat("filename", 777)' rights are -r----x--t That is why I need that first zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%04d:` the 0 means leading Zeros in 4 digits.

e.g.:

```
printf("%04d", hexanum);
```

If you want it in an string use `sprintf` instead of `printf`. The number (`int hexa_num`) itself doesn't have leading zeros but you can format it, just as you have your binary number not as a number but as a character string.